# PHP File_Get_Contents()

Tags: php, arrays, string, file, iostream

I have a very long text file (300 000 characters) with data delimited by a comma.

aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,ffff,gg,hhhhh,ii,j,kkkkkkkkkkkkk,l,mm

I'd like to populate the data into a string but by parts. For example, the first 100 pieces of data, then the next. Take note that the length of each piece of data varies unpredictably.

Is there a quick way to do this? I'd like to populate the data into a string in parts because I don't want to use too much memory at a time. So somewhat like a loop:

```
for ($counter = 0; $counter < $somenumber; $counter++) {
// (1) extract counter-th 100 pieces of data to string
// (2) explode string with , as delimiter so I can obtain an array
// (3) do something to this array
}
```

Can I use file_get_contents? Or what can I use?

Comment: you can try explode() [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) I don't really know how it processes it, but you can get an array of string chunks and work with them

Comment: many have missed the crux of the question, which was that "Take note that the length of each piece of data varies unpredictably." and that the string has to be loaded "in parts". The problem: file_get_contents needs to know where the 100th entry ends - the character number is needed for the 4th parameter of file_get_contents. But how does one get that character number without using strpos (as that will defeat the purpose as the entire string has to be loaded first to do that)

Comment: 300k characters is not a "very long" file. However, it is long enough that I would suggest using a read loop rather than reading the whole thing into memory at once.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `file_get_contents`. After that, you can use `explode` http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php to explode your file in several parts.

In your case, use:

```
$result = explode(",", $your_file_content);
```

You'll end up with an array, in `$result[0]` there will be the first part until your first comma, in `$result[1]` will be the second and so on. Means if you have something like:

> aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee

Then you'll have:

```
$result[0] // aaa
$result[1] // bbb
$result[2] // ccc
$result[3] // ddd
$result[4] // eee
```

After that, you can use a simple look to add the together to a string. For example something like:

```
for($a = 0; $a < 101; $a++) {
   $string .= $result[$a];
}
```

For sure this won't work this way, since your `$result` array will have more than 100 entries, but with a second `for-loop` outside the first one you should achieve what you're trying quite fast.

Comment: `php_explode` is not a valid function, I guess it has to be `explode` :)

Comment: @C0dekid Thx, edited. Link and codesample was already fine, just the name was wrong.

Comment: @C0dekid you missed the crux of the question, which was that "Take note that the length of each piece of data varies unpredictably." and that the string has to be loaded "in parts". The problem: file_get_contents needs to know where the 100th entry ends - the character number is needed for the 4th parameter of file_get_contents. But how does one get that character number without using strpos (as that will defeat the purpose as the entire string has to be loaded first to do that)

Answer (score 0):

You can use fread to read batch of the file, for example 8192Byte.

```
<?php
  $handle = fopen("filepath", "r");
  $content = '';
  $flag = false;
  while (!feof($handle)) {
    $content .= fread($handle, 8192);
    if(substr($content, -1) == ',')
      $flag = true;
    $array = explode(',', $content);
    if($flag)
    {
      $content = '';
    }
    else
    {
      $content = end($array);
      $array = array_pop($array);
    }
  }
  $array[] = $content;
  fclose($handle);
```